# PHP AJAX Json send object error

Tags: php, ajax

```
var workerEdit = { 
    id: id, 
    name: $('#workers_response input[name="name"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val(),
    photo: $('#workers_response input[name="pas-scan"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]')[0].files[0],
    bibliography: $('#workers_response textarea[name="bibliography"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val(),
    history: $('#workers_response textarea[name="history"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val(), 
    salary: $('#workers_response input[name="salary"][data-id="gear-'+id+'"]').val()
}
```

i create this object, then i use ajax to send data throw method POST:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/admin-workers/edit_worker.php",
    data: 'edit_worker='+JSON.stringify(input_data),

    success: function(data) { 
        var obj = JSON.parse(data); 
        if(obj.error === undefined) { 
            console.log(obj); 
            if(obj.data === null) { 
                alert("Успех"); 
            } 
        } 
        else { 
            alert("Ошибка: "+obj.error); 
            console.log(obj); 
        } 
    }, 
});
```

and in php i use:

```
$edit_worker = json_decode($_POST['edit_worker']);
$test = $edit_worker->name;
```

Why doesn't php get the object?

Comment: In your browser's debugging tools, what are the actual details of the AJAX request?  Is it a POST request?  What does the data look like?  In the server-side code, if `$_POST['edit_worker']` doesn't contain valid JSON, does it contain anything at all?  What are its raw contents?

Comment: Show the full code, those two ajax lines aren't enough

Comment: It's possible `data` should be a key-value object, not a string. Look at the request.

Comment: Check the network tab in dev tools and see the status of the request...

Comment: added more information

Comment: Kind of hard to tell, but you should probably escape JSON.stringify(workerEdit) as well. Try and print the contents of $_POST['edit_worker'] to see if it's JSON or gibberish

Comment: Print don't give anything...

Comment: Multiple have asked... what is the status of the request???? @СтаниславСтроянецкий

Comment: You can try print_r($_POST); to see if your server side gets any data

Comment: what is `input_data`? It's not defined in your snippet. It looks like the variable containing the data you wanted to send is called `workerEdit` so this is a bit puzzling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not properly serialized. You cannot just stringify a JSON map and POST it as `'edit_worker='+JSON.stringify(input_data)` It should look like this:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3
```

On the backend, you will extract individual values by their keys:

```
If ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $val1 = ( isset($_POST['val1']) ) ? trim($_POST['val1']) : '';
    $val2 = ( isset($_POST['val2']) ) ? trim($_POST['val2']) : '';
    // etc. etc. 

}
```

Your validation probably needs to contain more than just trim, depending upon what the data source is and what you're doing with it, but that's another discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an object with variable workerEdit but your are posting the data from input_data.  It appears you are not posting any data because of incorrect variable names.